# Using Recursive Functions in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I found this piece of code in MSDN documentation as an example of recursive functions: The link is provided below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/recursive-procedures

```
Function Factorial(n As Integer) As Integer ......'statement 1
    If n <= 1 Then
        Return 1
    End If
    **Return Factorial(n - 1) * n** 'Statement II: Not understanding how this helps calculating the factorial
End Function
```

Although I do understand how recursive functions work, I do not understand how statement II is calculating the factorial. For example say we enter n =5, in the first step. Then as per my understanding the first part of the statement II `Return **Factorial(n - 1)**` shall call the Factorial function in statement I and send the parameter n-1 = 4. And this is where my first question is: When we are calling Factorial function in statement I from statement II and passing the parameter (n-1) which equals 4 we are also multiplying it by n....what exactly are we returning in statement II...? In other words can someone explain in a step by step manner how the factorial value is getting calculated?

Also i tried using this piece of code to write a full program but unfortunately i could not make it work. To make it work I had to introduce a second parameter in the Factorial function - a parameter that would actually store the calculated value. I have provided the code below. My second question is: Is it possible to simplify the code I have written...the idea is not to use the second parameter "fact"...Is that possible?

The code that I wrote is as follows:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim number As Integer
        Dim fact As Integer = 1
        Console.Write("Please enter number: ")
        number = Console.ReadLine()
        Factorial(number, fact)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    Function Factorial(ByVal n As Integer, ByVal fact As Integer) As Integer
        If n > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Current Value of n = {0}", n)
        End If

        If n < 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Factorial = {0}", fact)
            Return 1
        End If
        fact = fact * n
        Return Factorial(n - 1, fact)
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on the call to `Factorial()` (e.g., `dim fact = Factorial(5)`) and follow, step by step, the whole procedure? If you do, you'll see how a recursive method actually works. `Return Factorial(n - 1) * n` is calculated only in the end, multiplying - backwards - all calculated `Factorial(n - 1)` by `n` in each step, after all calls to `Factorial(n - 1)` return a value.

Comment: Do you know, what factorial (function) means in mathematics? Helps to understand idea of recursive functions for sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the recursive function:

```
Function Factorial(n As Integer) As Integer
    If n <= 1 Then
        Return 1
    End If
    Return Factorial(n - 1) * n
End Function
```

And a initial call with value of 5:

```
Dim result As Integer = Factorial(5)
```

You'd get this sequence:

```
Call    What gets returned
----    -----------------------
F(5)    Return Factorial(4) * 5
F(4)    Return Factorial(3) * 4
F(3)    Return Factorial(2) * 3
F(2)    Return Factorial(1) * 2
F(1)    Return 1
```

When we get to F(1), we return a 1, then we "unwind" and move backwards up the call chain, substituting the return value into the previous line where the recursive call was.  At each point during the unwind, a new integer value will be calculated (and returned) until we end up with the final answer that gets returned by the original recursive call and assigned to the "result" variable:

```
Return 1
Return 2 ' 1 * 2
Return 6 ' 2 * 3
Return 24 ' 6 * 4
Return 120 ' 24 * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in learning how recursion works then Idle_Mind's answer is good.  However, if you just want to computer the factorial of a number, this is much simpler:

```
Dim Factorial As Integer = 1
For i As Integer = 1 To N
    Factorial *= i
Next
```

where N is the number for which the factorial is desired.

Comment: What if the input value is 1?

Comment: Actually i wanted to understand how recursion works